# Использование ~. (Tilde) в R

Tags: r

example ~ .

как можно после точки указать, какие переменные следует убрать, имеется ввиду, существует ли запись вида example ~ .-var1 -var2? или в любом случае придется выбирать эти переменные select'ом?

Comment: мне кажется, что всегда надежнее убирать через ```select```. однако я бы в этом случае попробовал ```~.-c(var1, var2)```, наверное. но я не уверен, что так что-то сработает.

Answer (score 0):

судя по описанию функции [`formula()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/topics/formula):

> The `-` operator removes the specified terms, so that `(a+b+c)^2 - a:b` is identical to `a + b + c + b:c + a:c`.

запись формулы вида `example ~ .-var1 -var2` вполне допустима и означает именно то, что вам требуется — исключение указанных переменных.

проверим. вот все переменные участвуют:

```r
lm(mpg~.,mtcars) %>% coefficients %>% names
#>  [1] "(Intercept)" "cyl"         "disp"        "hp"          "drat"       
#>  [6] "wt"          "qsec"        "vs"          "am"          "gear"       
#> [11] "carb"
```

а теперь попробуем исключить парочку:

```r
lm(mpg~.-cyl-disp,mtcars) %>% coefficients %>% names
#> [1] "(Intercept)" "hp"          "drat"        "wt"          "qsec"       
#> [6] "vs"          "am"          "gear"        "carb"
```

действительно, эти переменные не участвовали в построении модели.

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>